# Find local minima, maxima, and saddle points for $f(x,y) = \sin x + \cos y + \cos(x-y)$ when $0\le x\le\frac\pi2$ and $0\le y\le\frac\pi2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What I have done for this problem:

I differentiated $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$. Then, I set $f_x$ and $f_y$ to $0$ to find stationary points.

$$f(x,y) = \sin(x) + \cos(y) + \cos(x-y)$$
$$f_x = \cos(x) - \sin(x-y)$$
$$f_y = -\sin(y) + \sin(x-y)$$
$$f_x = f_y = 0$$
$$\cos(x) = \sin(x-y)$$
$$\sin(y) = \sin(x-y)$$
$$\cos(x) = \sin(y)$$ Note: $\cos(x) = \sin(y)$ implies $\cos(y) = \sin(x)$.
$$\sin(\pi/2 - x) = \sin(y)$$
$$y = \pi/2 - x \,\,\{0\le x \le\pi/2, 0\le y \le\pi/2\}$$

Using the Second Derivative Test, I categorized the points on the line segment ($y=\pi/2 - x$).

$$f_{xx} = -\sin(x) - \cos(x-y)$$
$$f_{yy} = -\cos(y) - \cos(x-y)$$
$$f_{xy} = \cos(x-y)$$
$$f_{yx} = \cos(x-y)$$

$$D = f_{xx}f_{yy} - f_{xy}f_{yx}$$
$$D = \cos(y)(\cos(y) + 2\cos(x-y))$$

Finally, the Second Derivative Test is inconclusive when $y = \pi/2$ and $x = 0$, and for all the other points on the line segment $f(x,y)$ when $0 \lt x \le \pi/2$ and $0\le y \lt \pi/2$ represents local maximum because $D \gt 0$ and $f_{xx} \lt 0$. This does not make sense because when I graph $f(x,y)$ on Desmos 3D graphing calculator it only shows one local maximum and one local minimum (https://www.desmos.com/3d/326ec8bd3d).

Comment: This is not homework for my course. I am a undergraduate student taking a higher-level proof based analysis, but I found this problem interesting and tried to solve it but failed.

Comment: See the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for tips on writing math on this site. (This is the preferred means of showing work, rather than linking images)

Comment: Please upvote if you also find this problem interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems more difficult than necessary because you haven't found the critical point properly.

It turns out that there is a unique critical point in the domain $[0, \pi/2] \times [0, \pi/2]$ that lies at the intersection of the curves $f_x = 0$ and $f_y = 0$.

Let's solve the first equation:
$$
\cos x - \sin(x-y) = 0.
$$
Using the cofunction identity
$\cos x = \sin\bigl(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\bigr)$, our equation becomes
$$
\sin\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x\bigr) = \sin(x-y).
$$
Since the arguments satisfy
$0 \leq \frac{\pi}{2} - x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and
$-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x - y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ on our domain, and the sine function is one-to-one there, we can conclude that
$$
\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x = x - y
$$
or
$$
y = 2x - \tfrac{\pi}{2}.
$$
All the points on this line satisfy $f_x = 0$.

I will let you solve $f_y = 0$.

> We get $f_y = 0$ at points on the line $y = \frac12 x$.

Now, we solve these two linear equations simultaneously to find the critical point

> $$(x, y) = \bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{3}, \tfrac{\pi}{6}\bigr).$$

Here's a picture of level curves, lines $f_x = 0$ and $f_y = 0$, and the critical point.

> [image: Level curves of function with critical point.]

From there, you can use the second derivative test to conclude:

> $f$ achieves a maximum value of $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$ at the critical point.

Comment: Just a simple question about your format: how did you put the graph on your post?

Comment: There's a button in the row of formatting buttons above the box where you edit your post/answer. Also the keyboard shortcut `<ctrl-G>` works. Make sure there's a blank line before/after, and also it's nice to include a brief caption.